# Why placeholder doesn't show its last element?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Can someone explain why placeholder doesn't show its last element?

Instead of this: "Search Google or type a **URL**"

It shows this: "Search Google or type a **UR**".

**I tried to delete all css code but it didn't help.**

```css
.google-search {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" class="google-search">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `width` instead of `padding-right`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .google-search{
      font-family:'Arial';
      padding-left:12px;
      width: 250px;
      padding-top:6px;
      padding-bottom:6px;
      border:none;
      box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      border-radius:20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" class="google-search">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the field looks very wide, that is just due to the `250px` of `padding` on the right hand side.

The `placeholder` (and any text you might type inside the field or put in a `value` attribute) gets cut off at the edge of the *content* width area.

Answer (score 0):

Just give width to the input feild. this will solve your problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .google-search{
      font-family:'Arial';
      padding-left:12px;
      padding-right:250px;
      padding-top:6px;
      padding-bottom:6px;
      border:none;
      box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      border-radius:20px;
      width: 50%
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" class="google-search">
</body>
</html>
```